# How to connect an Ember.js Controller to a View

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following structure in my Ember app:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('shop', { path: '/shop' });
});

App.ShopRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return $.getJSON( "/fruits"); // this returns a json like this: { apples: [...], oranges: [...]}
    }
});

App.AppleListItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'apple-list-item',
    tagName: 'li',
    classNames: ['apple']
});

App.AppleListItemController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    color: "green",
});
```

Next, when I try to use `{{color}}` in the apple-list-item template, it prints nothing. How should I fix this?

Comment: worry about naming, you should

Comment: You mean ApplesListItemView should be AppleListItemView? That's how it is in the original code, I corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to worry about your naming. A `shop` route in your router, expects a `ShopRoute` and a `ShopController`, but we can leave that out ember will generate one for you. and a `shop` template. You should consider your view an **optional** extension of your template. Ember always has an `index` route so you need an `index` template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{#link-to 'shop'}}shop!{{/link-to}}
</script>
```

And a shop template with an `itemController` in the `each` adding a controller to each element in the apples list:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="shop">
  SHOP! {{color}}
  <ul>
    {{#each apple in model.apples itemController='apple'}}
      <li class="apple">{{apple.model}} {{apple.color}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

And then your application would look somehting like:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('shop', { path: '/shop' });
});
```

With a `ShopRoute`:

```
App.ShopRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return { apples: [ 'grannysmith', 'pinklady' ], oranges: [ 'clementines' ]};
    }
});
```

And a `AppleController` to be used as `itemController`:

```
App.AppleController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    color: function() {
      if (this.get('model') === 'grannysmith') {
        return 'green';
      }
      return 'purple';                                        
    }.property('model'),
});
```

See this [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/solica/6/edit).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the problem is that I'd need to add an extra property, color, for each apple object. In your example, the color variable is added to the shop context, not in apple context.

Comment: Btw, I edited TutorialRoute to ShopRoute. Sorry for that, it was kind of typo in the question.